# problem error 404 jsp not found project spring boot and jboss

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, jboss

i have problem mapping with my jsp i have error 404. I try working with client-server Jboss(i have not chose). I have try starter with springbootapplication or jboss. When i started with springbootapplication application doesn't work but it start and jboss i have acces online page 8080 home page jboss

Controller formulaire

```
@Controller
public class RequestController {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test log 1");

    @Autowired
    RddRepository rddRepository;

    @GetMapping("/formulaire")
    public String showFormulaire(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("formulaire", new Formulaire());
        logger.info("test appel jsp requeteform");
        return "formulaire";
    }


    @PostMapping("/requeteFormulaire")
    public String save(@Valid Formulaire formulaire, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        RddRepository.save(formulaire);
        return "requeteFormulaire";
    }
```

formulaire.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Formulaire Requete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-7">
        <h2 class="text-center">Formulaire jeu test</h2>
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">Formulaire</div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form:form action="/save" Class="form-horizontal">



                         <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="identifiant" class="col-md-3 control-label">code compte</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <form:input path="identifiant" maxlength="9" Class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                            <form:button type="submit" value="Save" Class="btn btn-primary">Creer</form:button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

application.propertises

```
server.port=8080
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RequeteBddJeuTestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {




   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(RequeteBddJeuTestApplication.class);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(RequeteBddJeuTestApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your return statements with directly `.jsp` file name.

i.e.

```
    return "formulaire";

    return "requeteFormulaire";
```

Sprint MVC will automatically find the path with prefix/suffix given in properties file.

Comment: I thanks for you answer but the return is good. I have two jsp : 1.first the answer submit  the formulaire. 2 the second jsp, application show the answer of user.